# How to update .aspx files with the contents of the .resx file

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, localization

Basically, what I'm looking for is the opposite of `Generate Local Resource` feature.

Occasionally when we send our `.resx` files to translators for localization the original strings are also modified to correct typos. Now if I simply overwrite the old `.resx` with the new ones, the `.aspx` file still contains the old typo and the error will be reintroduced in the `.resx` file the next time someone runs the `Generate Local Resource` function.

Is there a way around this issue or a feature to bring the `.resx` contents back to the `.aspx` file? or do I have to write my own tool for this function?

The number of translated pages is too big to do this manually.